# How to query filter by date using hibernate, HSQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hsqldb

Good afternoon , I need to filter a query by date, the date is defined in the database as:
 **y: m: d**.
It 's performed with sqlnativo in hibernate but it returns null.
anyone can help me , also if someone can explain me how to handle criteria with dates, since I do not find any clear example

```
    Query query = session.createSQLQuery("Select  id,fecha,total,idEnvio FROM VENTA_CABECERA vc WHERE date(fecha) = :fec" ).addEntity(HeadSale.class);
query.setParameter("fec", date);
return query.list();
```

It can also be the between clause , but honestly I can not make it work. would be grateful to give me a solution.
regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the format of `"fec" parameter` as **y: m: d** and remove `date` function inside query

```
DateFormat df;    
df= new SimpleDateFormat("y: m: d");
String dt= sdf.format(date);    
Query query = session.createSQLQuery
("Select  id,fecha,total,idEnvio FROM VENTA_CABECERA vc WHERE fecha = :fec" )
.addEntity(HeadSale.class);
query.setParameter("fec", dt);
return query.list();
```